# Ionic capacitor camera-preview pwa show black screen in IOS

Tags: ios, typescript, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

Currently, I'm develop pwa using ionic and need to use capacitor camera-preview. It can access the camera in chrome desktop, android browser, and safari macOS except in safari iOS. It will show black screen even thought it already ask the permission in safari.

When I try view at web inspector, it shows the error like this

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

**camera.page.ts**

```
import { Plugins } from "@capacitor/core";
const { CameraPreview } = Plugins;
import { CameraPreviewOptions,CameraPreviewPictureOptions,CameraPreviewWeb } from '@capacitor-community/camera-preview';

openCamera() {
       
  
        const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: window.screen.width,
            height: window.screen.height,
            parent: 'cameraPreview',
            className: 'cameraPreview',
            position: 'rear',
             toBack: true
        }
        CameraPreview.start(cameraPreviewOpts).then((res) => {
            console.log('start camera success', res);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log('start camera error', err);
        });

    }

    takePicture() {
        console.log('capturing');

        const pictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
            width: 1280,
            height: 1280,
            quality: 30
        }

        CameraPreview.capture(pictureOpts).then((imageData) => {
         
            this.ionViewWillLeave();

        }, (err) => {
            console.log('take picture error', err);
            // this.cameraPreview.stopCamera();
        });
    }
```

**camera.page.html**

```
<ion-content id="camera-content" class="camera-content">

  <div style="text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="cameraPreview" class="cameraPreview"> 
    <img *ngIf="passType == 'ocr'" src="assets/rsz-scan-area.png" class="frame">
 
    <img src="assets/capture-button.png" class="capture-button" (click)="takePicture()">

 </div>
```

It have any configuration need to setup or anything that I need to do to overcome this issues?

**Updated**
it can capture the image but still shows black screen when open the camera

Black screen when access the camera:
[access camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gGe8.jpg)
Result when camera capture image:
[camera success capture the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpAaB.jpg)

Comment: add camera permission in info.plist file

Comment: @RaviAshara I already add all permission. It can capture the image but still show the black screen on the camera

Comment: Oh Okay, can you please share screenshot or video??

Comment: check this repo: https://github.com/Kaoschuks/ionic-media-editor

Comment: @RaviAshara I already update the question above

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I try it in iOS with that code, still can't access for camera preview part